# SSH host-based authentication

Tags: linux, networking, bash, ssh

I have a client and a server which are both based on Slackware (version 10.2.0 / kernel 2.6.15.4). I want to connect form the client to the server with ssh host-based authentication. That's what I have done so far. Of course I have an entry in /etc/hosts for each machine (client and IP on server; server and IP on client).

```
Client:
vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config -> EnableSSHKeySign yes, HostbasedAuthentication yes
ssh-keyscan server >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
/etc/rc.d/rc.sshd stop
/etc/rc.d/rc.sshd start

Server:
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config -> HostbasedAuthentication yes, IgnoreRhosts no
touch /etc/ssh/shosts.equiv
vim /etc/ssh/shosts.equiv -> client root
ssh-keyscan client >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
touch ~/.shosts -> client root
/etc/rc.d/rc.sshd stop
/etc/rc.d/rc.sshd start
```

When I try to ssh from my client on server with

```
ssh server
```

I receive the following error:

> get_socket_address: getnameinfo 8 failed: Name or service not known
> userauth_hostbased: cannot get local ipaddr/name

The whole log with verbose ssh is:

```
OpenSSH_4.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7g 11 Apr 2005
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to server [192.168.1.102] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_4.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
debug1: Next authentication method: hostbased
get_socket_address: getnameinfo 8 failed: Name or service not known
userauth_hostbased: cannot get local ipaddr/name
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@server's password:
```

My /etc/hosts on the client looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 client.local client

192.168.1.101 client
192.168.1.102 server
```

and the /etc/hosts on the server like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 server.local server

192.168.1.101 client
192.168.1.102 server
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your /etc/hosts entry might be wrong.  Having seen your /etc/hosts files:

I'd recommend removing the whole lines:

```
127.0.0.1 server.local server
```

and

```
127.0.0.1 client.local client
```

it would be fine to let client and client.local both point to 192.168.1.101, rather than have one of them point to 127.0.0.1, like:

```
192.168.1.101 client client.local
```

The main point is that "server" and "client" should each appear only once in the file, or it gets confused.  I imagine it uses the first time the name appears in the file.

One way you can check is to see if you can ping the server from the client.  If ping also fails, that would also indicate /etc/hosts is wrong.  If it suceeds, something else is wrong.

On the client:

```
ping server
```

In addition:

It could also be that it is not looking in /etc/hosts.  Check out /etc/nsswitch.conf.  You are looking for a line like:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

If that line does not have 'files' in it, you need to add that.  That is what makes it look in /etc/hosts to try to resolve names into IP addresses.

Comment: I've added the /ect/hosts files from both server and client

Answer (score 0):

> Remove client from "127.0.0.1 client.local client" in /etc/hosts file on client machine as following :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 client.local 

192.168.1.101 client
192.168.1.102 server
```

> Remove 'server' from "127.0.0.1 server.local server" in /etc/hosts file on sever as following :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 server.local 

192.168.1.101 client
192.168.1.102 server
```